# URL validator for JEE6 Beans Validation 1.0

Tags: java-ee-6, bean-validation

How can I create a custom validator for a URL field in Beans Validation 1.0.
But how can I pass the URL string passed via JSON into my constraint validator?

```
@ValidURL
private URL myUrl;
```

---

```
public class URLValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidURL, CharSequence> {...}
```

---

```
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {URLValidator.class})
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
public @interface ValidURL {

    String message() default "must be a valid URL";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

I know the latest Hibernate Validator has a @URL validation but I cannot move to the latest version.

**Edit:**
With the above I am hitting the following. So my question is how does Hibernate convert the URL type to the CharSequence used by the ConstraintValidator?

```
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.net.URL.
```

Comment: What are you actually asking? You seem to know how to write a custom constraint. How you get your URL from some sort of JSON request into the Java model will depend on the frameworks you are using. You are not giving any information about this here. Also, Hibernate Validator's @URL constraint is available in the 4.x version as well, so why can you not use it?

Answer (score 0):

Doh, Just realized the Hibernate validator @URL is for String type not java.net.URL